# DocuSign Connect not sending all Conditional Tabs upon completion

Tags: docusignapi

I have DocuSign Connect sending a response when the document is complete. I have it include the Document Fields when Connect publishes to my listener.

Yet when I examine the fields they send, they do not include the Conditional Fields unless the condition has been met. I'm hidding data within the document that is not user friendly and I'm trying to retrieve both the visible and hidden tabs upon completion.

I can pull the values by querying the REST API:
https://(url)/restapi/(version)/accounts/(account)/envelopes/(envelope id)/recipients/(recipient id)/tabs

But is there a way for DocuSign Connect to send it to me directly upon completion?

Answer (score 1):

- As an alternative, you can always place these tags on the document, all at the same x/y coordinate (overlapping), lock the tabs, and make the font color white (to match the documents background for example). It will not be visible to a recipient, but still parseable by your system and included in the DS Connect message.
- There are also envelope and document level custom fields you can leverage per the documentation.